# Why is 'p2pkh:' prepended at the beginning of private key addresses in electrum?

Tags: wallet, private-key, electrum, p2pkh

I recently started a Blockchain course and came across the electrum software. While going through the list of wallet addresses and associated private keys I found that  'p2pkh' is placed at the start of every private key, why is that?
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A single private key can lead to different addresses, depending on the script it is used in - These include p2pkh, p2wpkh, p2sh-p2wpkh.

Electrum prepends the script type to the private key during export and import so that it knows which address to derive and check for outputs on.